# Having(count) in a Cakephp 3 query fails on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

I have the following table structure with matching relations:

```
   ,---------.   ,--------------.    ,---------.
   | Threads |   | ThreadsUsers |    |  Users  |
   |---------|   |--------------|    |---------|
   |   id    |   |      id      |    |    id   |
   '---------'   |  thread_id   |    '---------'
                 |    user_id   |
                 '--------------'
```

This custom query in ThreadsTable is meant to find threads with a given number of participants. It works fine on mysql

```
public function findWithUserCount(Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query
        ->matching('Users')
        ->select([
            'Threads.id',
            'count' => 'COUNT(Users.id)'
        ])
        ->group('Threads.id HAVING count = ' . $options['count']);
}
```

However it fails on postgresql with the following error

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 
       ERROR: column "count" does not exist
LINE 1: ...ThreadsUsers.user_id)) GROUP BY Threads.id HAVING count = 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HAVING` clause cannot reference column aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause. The [documentation says](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING):

> Each column referenced in condition must unambiguously reference a grouping column, unless the reference appears within an aggregate function or the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouping columns.

Since `count` is neither a "grouping column" (i.e. the subject of the `GROUP BY` clause) nor an aggregate function, it can't be used there.

So the correct form would presumably be (I don't know CakePHP, and the fact that you can inject SQL into the `group` call at all seems like a massively broken design for a query builder):

```
->group('Threads.id HAVING COUNT(Users.id) = ' . $options['count']);
```

Comment: Thanks, @IMSoP, it works for me, i had use following snippe

    public function findWithUserCount(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        return $query
            ->matching('Users')
            ->select(['Threads.id'])
            ->group('Threads.id')
            ->having('COUNT(Users.id) = ' . $options['count']);
    }